# newsletter popup after 15secs on site? [magento2]

Tags: magento2, newsletter, popup

Does someone know how or where to get a popup on magento2 after 15 seconds, which collects email addresses for newsletter?
Is there a good free extension or is it better to make it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem when you make a time popup is that the modal opens for each page view and if the user changes the page, the 15 seconds restarts from zero.

So in addiction to the things written before, I suggest to use a cookie to store the session and preserve your countdown.

So in your definition function you can write:

```
define([

    "jquery",
    "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal",
    "mage/cookies",

], function($,modal) {
```

It's not so fine that the same user sees the popup each time he visit a page, but you can set a cookie when your user see the newsletter box for the first time. So just after opening the modal you can write something like:

```
 $.mage.cookies.set(cookie, 'yes',{lifetime: 342342342342});
```

Now you can open the modal only if the cookie is set to yes:

```
    if ($.mage.cookies.get(cookie) == 'yes') {
       // Open the modal
    }
```

To preserve the countdown you have to track the time from the first page load to the newsletter appearance. So start a countdown at DOM ready and update your cookie value:

```
    callback = callback || function(){};
    var int = setInterval(function() {
        $.mage.cookies.set('popup-timing', i);
        i-- || (clearInterval(int), callback());
    }, 1000);
```

Now you can set a timeout and open the modal exactly after 15 seconds since the cookie was set for the first time.

[I've already done this](https://github.com/bitbull-team/magento2-module-newsletterpopup) for an internal project. Try if it fit for you.

Comment: Please explain some thing, donot put only link

Comment: You are right. I'll edit the post

Comment: Absolutely amazing! Exactly what I wanted. Works great! :D Could you tell me how I could make the title of the modal "font-weight:bold;" with inline css? Which file? Also, would it be possible to add an image in the modal? Thanks alot man!! :))

Comment: Edit (in your theme) view/frontend/templates/newsletter/popup.phtml

Comment: Thx. I've managed to add an image now but I cannot see any "modal-title" where I could style it inline..

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I was confused with the text. Title is added by the magento modal component. You can see in web/js/newsletter.js at line 26 title: $.mage.__(this.options.title). I hope (not sure) you can do title: $.mage.__(<span style="...">this.options.title<span>). Otherwise you can remove the title from js/css and add it back in phtml.

Comment: Hey :) The above one doesn't work. When I remove it from the JS, how and where to add it in the popup.html? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Popup with custom theme**

Just follow this step to display popup with newsletter after 5 seconds(You can change it as your need) on homepage

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Cms/js/popup.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\template" name="index.home" template="Magento_Cms::popup.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/templates/popup.phtml

```
<div id="popup-content" class="popup-content" style="display:none">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe")->setTemplate("Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml")->toHtml();?>
</div>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/web/js/popup.js

```
require(
    ['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'],
    function($, modal) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            modal({
                autoOpen: true,
                responsive: true,
                clickableOverlay: false,
                modalClass: 'modal-custom',
                title: 'Popup'
            }, $("#popup-content"));
        },5000);
    }
);
```

Now clear cache and do static-content deploy

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for display **popup with custom module**

Just follow this step to display popup with newsletter after 5 second(You can chnage it as your need) on homepage

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Vendor_Module/js/popup.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\template" name="index.home" template="Vendor_Module::popup.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/popup.phtml

```
<div id="popup-content" class="popup-content" style="display:none">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe")->setTemplate("Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml")->toHtml();?>
</div>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/popup.js

```
require(
    ['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'],
    function($, modal) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            modal({
                autoOpen: true,
                responsive: true,
                clickableOverlay: false,
                modalClass: 'modal-custom',
                title: 'Popup'
            }, $("#popup-content"));
        },5000);
    }
);
```